# How can I make that seems there is a CD inserted when I was just only plugged in my USB?

Tags: usb, disk, usb-drive, autorun

I was fascinated with that trick when I saw that my new USB got plugged into the computer and then, two autorun windows popped up immediately. The only thing which had been plugged is that USB and two item autoran, and even the disk label turned into two: one for the virtual disc and another for the USB. How is that done and possible?
I saw that there is a hidden program in the new USB, is that related to the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is *Virtual CD*

there are some utilities to create a virtual CD in win and linux

- http://smallbusiness.chron.com/create-virtual-dvd-cd-usb-drive-56826.html
- http://www.allarghiamoci.it/usbcdrom/

( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_CD-ROM_switching_utility#ZeroCD )